# Replace ListPickerPage with custom Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I added the Windows Phone Toolkit with Nuget into my project.

Now I want to replace the default ListPickerPage with a custom page like this can be achieved for the DatePickerPage. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/21/there-are-lots-of-ways-to-ask-for-a-date-creating-custom-datepicker-timepicker-experiences-is-easy-with-the-windows-phone-toolkit.aspx)

Unfortunately this page does not provide an interface from which I could inherit.
The ListPicker.cs seems to have the reference hard coded:

```
private ListPickerPage _listPickerPage;
```

Even though it supports the PickerPageUri property.
I copied the ListPickerPage.xaml and code behind from the Source Repository and provided the path to this page as PickerPageUri. 
The Page is opened but contains no content!
I think the reason is this part of code in the ListPicker.cs:

```
_listPickerPage = e.Content as ListPickerPage;
```

My class is not a "ListPickerPage" and therefore the reference remains null and no values will be set.
Next step I tried was to inherit from ListPickerPage to get the cast done.
Problem here: the public properties Items and some others have "private set" properties.

At the end, I always ended up with an empty target page.

Google + StackOverflow stated many times that one has to copy the page and simply refer to it via PickerPageUri, but this alone seems not to work.

Has anybody managed to get an own ListPickerPage in his project?

Comment: Well, it is an open source project and you can change and recompile it for your own purposes.

Comment: I know, but it is a lot better to include it is Nuget Package to get all updates than rewriting some of the code and performing the update manually.